# Insert and remove a marker at the start of the current line

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, comments

So, I'm trying to set up a sort of bookmark/marker kind of workflow, and I came to notice I'm used to put characters such as `#` and such for different meaning inside my own notes, etc.

Now, I already know how to do the first part (inserting text at the start of a/the current line):

```
.s/^/#
```

And I also already know how to make a mapping of it. Problem is, I want to be able to also remove the placed marker *if it's already there*, and place one on the current line if it's not.

I'm unsure on how this should look like in vimscript. I don't mind using an existing plugin for this, but would prefer not to if possible.

Any feedback/answer appreciated.

Comment: Here's a sketch: first check if the current line starts with `#` with `getline('.') ~= '^#'`. If it does, remove it with `:s/^#//`, otherwise insert one with `:s/^/#`. Does this help?

Comment: Think I could work with this yeah. Thanks a lot for the suggestion :) @husB

Comment: Ok let me know how it goes. If you've figured it out feel free to post your own answer; otherwise comment here and I'll fill in more details :)

Comment: Made [this](https://termbin.com/hecm) so far. Don't think this work but the logic look like it could work. @husB

Comment: Nevermind, figured it all out :) will post shortly @husB

Comment: Nice, [that](https://termbin.com/hecm) should work :) Oops, it should have been `=~` instead of `~=` :x.

Comment: yeah, fixed it in my answer. Thanks again for the help! @husB

Comment: Related: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/6b7cf7fb45b7f331788287137726f48cd7eed09a/links/vim/autoload/bk/make.vim I remove the prefix before inserting it, and have separate mappings rather than toggle. You could also try a comment plugin like commentary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @husB's comment, seems I figured it out:

```
function Markerstart()
    if getline('.') =~ '^#'
        :s/^#//
    else
        :s/^/#/
    endif
endfunction
```

Then use `:call Markerstart` on a specific line, and it work.

Can be set up with `vnoremap` so it can work on multiple lines.

Comment: You don't need `exe` if the substitution consists of literal strings only. Just `s/^#//`.

Comment: I see. I tried them without `exe` at first, but noticed it had error for some reason... @BLayer

Comment: Were you using `"`? You shouldn't use quotes. Otherwise, it should work. I'll try it out to be sure.

Comment: yep, you're right; works without quote and `exe`. Will edit :) @BLayer Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the opening `:` either as you're in a purely Ex context...but it's harmless. :)

Comment: Gotcha. The more you know :D @BLayer